# Как в cmake проверить есть ли в системе соответствющий компилятор?

Tags: cmake

К примеру, у нас есть проект, который я хочу собирать `clang`-ом, но, если его нет на компе, собирать можно и `g++` компилятором. Как задать компилятор я знаю, но как проверить есть ли он?

Comment: А если нет, то автоматом установить, да? Типа "сквозь огонь и медные трубы"? Видимо cmake для баллистической ракеты.

Comment: Скорее: если нет, то оставить по умолчанию)

Answer (score 1):

CMake принято запускать из командной строки, явно указывая чем Вы собираетесь собирать проект. К примеру, если Вы хотите собирать с помощью Visual Studio, то мы пишем что-то такое в командной строке: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`, теперь CMake проверяет, есть ли такой компилятор на целевой машине и если его нет, то он выдаст ошибку.

Хотя пример выше использует Visual Studio, это справедливо для любого другого компилятора: мы явно указываем то, чем нужно собирать через командную строку вызова CMake и дальше уже его дело сообщить нам, нашёл ли он подходящий компилятор. Т.е. ответственность за проверку наличия компилятора уже лежит на CMake, нам лишь остаётся указать ему то, каким конкретно компилятором мы желаем воспользоваться.

Comment: Стоит добавить что `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` это генератор, а не компилятор. И компилятор не всегда определяется генератором.

Comment: @arrowd, это генератор для вполне конкретного компилятора (имя которого полностью совпадает с тем, что указано в строке). Не вижу смысла это уточнять.

Comment: Visual Studio - это IDE, а не компилятор. Смысл флага `-G` - указать файлы какой системы сборки надо сгенерить. Можно указать `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"`, а компилировать Clang'ом, а не `cl.exe`.

Comment: @arrowd, с вышеозначенной строчкой будет сгенерирован вполне конкретный solution, c вполне конкретным проектом, где в качестве компилятора будет тот, что является компилятором по умолчанию для "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64". И это не clang.

Comment: Ну с одной только `-G` - да, но можно же добавить `-T`. А может и `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` сработает, ни вникал.

Comment: @arrowd, ну да, а можно ещё кучу ключей добавить и все описать. Вот возьмитесь и опишите всё, вроде место для ответов ещё есть. А я написал то, что написал. На мой взгляд, я написал достаточно.